# problem in building workSpace in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing android application using Linux SDK in Eclipse. When i build my application its showing error as follows,

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Rpmlint project builder' on project 'Writing'.2
```

After this problem occurred , when i ran the code, its not running, and so i have to run once again for getting output. what is the problem? how to solve it?

When i googled, some one suggested to close Eclipse and restart it again. I have tried all those things but my problem persists.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking whether all of your assets are available, most of the problems I had using the SDK were due to the R.java file not being regenerated. Whenever the builder can't find an asset the building stops.

Comment: I have checked all but no use.. R.java is generating but still problem presists..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, solved removing the Rpmlint Warnings.

To remove the Rpmlint Warnings:

- Select the project in the "Project Explorer"
- Right click on the selection to open the contextual menu
- Select the entry "Add/Remove Rpmlint Warnings" to remove the warning